# Xcode 4 workspace with two projects can't access each other's files

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, workspace

I have two projects in a workspace.  Project A needs to access some files in Project B (Kal).  When I do an import (in Project A), I start the #import and a popup gives me choices of all the files I have available to me.  I choose Kal.h, and immediately get the red flag saying it can't find the file.

According to the [Apple Docs on Workspaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html), XCode should automatically find the file... is this not true?  Do I still have to set the search paths, etc?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The passage you quote indicates something slightly different than what you want.   In particular, the Workspace has access to both sets of files, but the peer projects do not have access to each other's files.

If your Project A needs access to files in Project B, you can set up your workspace that Project A includes a reference to Project B.  In this case, Project A will have access to Project B's files, although not vice-versa.   This will work for headers, or for object files.

To add one project to another project within a workspace, select the Project A in the workspace, and then choose `File > Add Files to Project A...` and select Project B's project file in the standard file window.   This will add it to Project A, giving Project A access to the Project B files.

Comment: Hi, I have done the same but whenever I am trying to import the files, it gives me error of file not found. Please tell me if there is any step that I am missing. I am however, importing the file as #import"FileName.h". The reference is correct as it is giving me an option of autocomplete file name.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose with that information.   To clarify, you're trying to #import Project B's files into Project A's source, as I described above?